# React nested json object error thiks it is object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I have interesting error.
Here I have a react file with axios that takes data from my post and even if that works on showing all post where i post all posts in one page i have problem with that i tried to find solution but couldn't.

so here is my code on react

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
var id = match.params.id;
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/post/' + id).then(res => {
        setPost(res.data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}, []);

return (
    <div >
        <div className="blogcontainer">
            <img src={post.images.destination + post.images.filename} alt={post.name} />
            <div className="articleWrapper">
                <h2>{post.name}</h2>
                {parse(String(post.postcontent))}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

)
```

The data it takes is:

```
data: {…}
​​
__v: 0
​​
_id: "5f4adaa46bde7743b4254615"
​​
createdAt: "2020-08-29T22:45:56.894Z"
​​
description: "At first write an introduction without pushing enter until complete introduction..."
​​
images: {…}
​​​
destination: "uploads/"
​​​
encoding: "7bit"
​​​
fieldname: "mainImage"
​​​
filename: "1598741156885.jpg"
​​​
mimetype: "image/png"
​​​
originalname: "iguda_logo.png"
​​​
path: "uploads\\1598741156885.jpg"
​​​
size: 758685
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
name: "fdhfgh"
​​
postcontent: "<p>At first write an introduction without pushing enter until complete introduction</p>"
```

and here is error:

```
TypeError: post.images is undefined
BlogArticle
C:/Users/arsla/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/inc-web/client/src/component/BlogArticle.jsx:23

  20 | return (
  21 |     <div >
  22 |         <div className="blogcontainer">
> 23 |             <img src={post.images.destination + post.images.filename} alt={post.name} />
     | ^  24 |             <div className="articleWrapper">
  25 |                 <h2>{post.name}</h2>
  26 |                 {parse(String(post.postcontent))}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the first render your state will be empty and so indeed all of the properties will be undefined. You need to check for that first and then render a spinner or empty div while a axios is fetching the data.

You can use a ternary operator to do it. Not sure why you're initialising your state with an empty array if you're only dealing with one post but if it is an array you check for `post.length` and if it's an object or anything else you can just check for `!post`

````
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
var id = match.params.id;
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/post/' + id).then(res => {
        setPost(res.data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}, []);

return (

    <div >
        <div className="blogcontainer">
            {post.length < 1 ? <div /> : 
                <img src={post.images.destination + post.images.filename} alt={post.name} />
                <div className="articleWrapper">
                    <h2>{post.name}</h2>
                    {parse(String(post.postcontent))}
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>


)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your return is called once u render the component.
There are couple of solutions for that solutions

1. don't render you component if you don't have data

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
var id = match.params.id;
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:3001/post/' + id).then(res => {
       setPost(res.data);
   }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
   })
}, []);
if(!post.images){
return
}
return (
   <div >
       <div className="blogcontainer">
           <img src={post.images.destination + post.images.filename} alt={post.name} />
           <div className="articleWrapper">
               <h2>{post.name}</h2>
               {parse(String(post.postcontent))}
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

)
```

2. If you want everything to render but the img Add an inline check in the img

```
<img src={post.images?.destination + post.images?.filename} alt={post.name} />
```

Comment: I have data that's the problem i have data and it shows when I log it but when i try to add something like post.images.<any subobject of images> i have that error

Comment: have u tried this ```<img src={post.images?.destination + post.images?.filename} alt={post.name} />```

Comment: yes i tried but don't have any output because it's don't see output but if you look at my json data it is there

Comment: can u share the exact json what you are getting in the API response.